# how to import sqlite datas into mysql?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, csv

im trying to import persian data to mysql database
currently im using sqlite
but when i import a csv file or making a query in mysql
all the data turn into question marks
something like this :
??? ???? ??????
what should i do??

Comment: That means the MySQL table you created does not have the proper Charset/Collation to support persian characters.

Comment: Convert your date to compatible format (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss) during saving the data to CSV. PS. MySQL does not support persian dates system.

Answer (score 0):

It came up to be an issue with collations.

I converted the import to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and the data was successfully imported !